# Angularjs : [$injector:modulerr] error

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I dont understand what is my mistake . When I load root url it shows `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]` , and also the "/ssh" is not  working . I am using 1.3.  Here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="hiren">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <base href="/" />

</head>
<body>
        <div class="col-sm-1" ng-view>

        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="src/hiren.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

hiren.js:

```
angular.module('hiren', ['ngRoute']).
    config( function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when('/ssh', {
                templateUrl: 'views/ssh.html',
                controller: 'ssh'

            });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }).
    controller('ssh', function($scope){
        $scope.xox = "example";
    });
```

Comment: There's usually a **lot** more to those error messages. They're even clickable through to an Angular page explaining the details

Comment: Two more points: 1) *"also the "/ssh" is not working"* is a **terrible** problem description. 2) You have nothing to handle the default request of `/`

Comment: Its serving from server side

Comment: I don't actually know what you're trying to say there. How about we just start with the **full** error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrap your angular code in a script tag and put it inside the html tag

```
<script>
angular.module('hiren', ['ngRoute']).
    config( function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when('/ssh', {
                templateUrl: 'views/ssh.html',
                controller: 'ssh'

            });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }).
    controller('ssh', function($scope){
        $scope.xox = "example";
    });

<script>
```